# Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb06b9940)

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I'm new to lldb and trying to diagnose an error by using `po [$eax class]`

The error shown in the UI is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

Here is the lldb console including what I entered and what was returned:

```
(lldb) po [$eax class]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb06b9940).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

The global breakpoint state toggle is off.

Answer (score 17):

You app is getting stopped because the code you are running threw an uncaught Mach exception.  Mach exceptions are the equivalent of BSD Signals for the Mach kernel - which makes up the lowest levels of the macOS operating system.

In this case, the particular Mach exception is `EXC_BREAKPOINT`.  `EXC_BREAKPOINT` is a common source of confusion...  Because it has the word "breakpoint" in the name people think that it is a debugger breakpoint.  That's not entirely wrong, but the exception is used more generally than that.

`EXC_BREAKPOINT` is in fact the exception that the lower layers of Mach reports when it executes a certain instruction (a trap instruction).  That trap instruction is used by lldb to implement breakpoints, but it is also used as an alternative to `assert` in various bits of system software.  For instance, swift uses this error if you access past the end of an array.  It is a way to stop your program right at the point of the error.  If you are running outside the debugger, this will lead to a crash.  But if you are running in the debugger, then control will be returned to the debugger with this `EXC_BREAKPOINT` stop reason.

To avoid confusion, lldb will never show you `EXC_BREAKPOINT` as the stop reason if the trap was one that lldb inserted in the program you are debugging to implement a debugger breakpoint.  It will always say `breakpoint n.n` instead.

So if you see a thread stopped with `EXC_BREAKPOINT` as its stop reason, that means you've hit some kind of fatal error, usually in some system library used by your program.  A backtrace at this point will show you what component is raising that error.

Anyway, then having hit that error, you tried to figure out the class of the value in the eax register by calling the class method on it by running `po [$eax class]`.  Calling that method (which will cause code to get run in the program you are debugging) lead to a crash.  That's what the "error" message you cite was telling you.

That's almost surely because `$eax` doesn't point to a valid ObjC object, so you're just calling a method on some random value, and that's crashing.

Note, if you are debugging a 64 bit program, then $eax is actually the lower 32 bits of the real argument passing register - $rax.  The bottom 32 bits of a 64 bit pointer is unlikely to be a valid pointer value, so it is not at all surprising that calling `class` on it led to a crash.

If you were trying to call class on the first passed argument (self in ObjC methods) on 64 bit Intel, you really wanted to do:

```
(lldb) po [$rax class]
```

Note, that was also unlikely to work, since `$rax` only holds `self` at the start of the function.  Then it gets used as a scratch register.  So if you are any ways into the function (which the fact that your code fatally failed some test makes seem likely) $rax would be unlikely to still hold `self`.

Note also, if this is a 32 bit program, then `$eax` is not in fact used for argument passing - 32 bit Intel code passes arguments on the stack, not in registers.

Anyway, the first thing to do to figure out what went wrong was to print the backtrace when you get this exception, and see what code was getting run at the time this error occurred.

Comment: @Jim Ingham Could you edit your `answer` for everyone easy to read? I think most people hard to understand your mean.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but could you please provide some snippet or image to explain your answers please

Comment: If you can tell me where I lost you in the answer above, I can try to expand on that area to make it clearer.

Comment: thank you for this explanation. Can you plz tell me how to print a backtrace in lldb ?

Comment: The basic lldb command is `thread backtrace` (see `help thread backtrace` for more details.). There's also a quick access alias `bt` to backtrace the current or a set of threads (or `all` for all threads).  lldb also has an `apropos` command that will search for keywords in the help: `apropos backtrace` for instance.  Finally, if you are coming from gdb https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html might help you get oriented.

Answer (score 7):

Clean project and restart Xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding my solution, as I've struggled with the same problem and I didn't find this solution anywhere.

In my case I had to run Product -> Clean Build Folder (Clean + Option key) and rebuild my project. Breakpoints and lldb commands started to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Runtime error**

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb06b9940)
```

Additionally this error you can watch when next argument in schema is on.

```
-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1
```